# Floating burger menu over container block element

Tags: css, css-float

I've got a bootstrap container which has styling of

```
.container {
    margin-top: 12em;
    font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    border-color: #800000;
}
```

The reason for this is that I want my nav bar on a desktop to be floating in the middle of the screen 12em from the top. It appears to be block display due to bootstrap auto styling.

When I switch to a mobile I've got a burger menu displaying, however I want this to be at the top right of the screen, its currently getting pushed down by the container, even when I float it. CSS below:

```
.navbar-toggle,
.collapsed {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1em;
    right: 1em;
}
```

Please help!

Comment: Do you mind to share your full code? Thanks.

Comment: What program do you suggest to share with?

Comment: Jsfiddle will do. Only for the navbar codes. I need more information about the template so I can help you to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Thank you, here is the fiddle - it doesnt seem to be displaying like it is on my pc due to bootstrap being installed https://jsfiddle.net/7xzgqyq8/1/

Comment: Does your toggle button have an ancestor with position: relative; or position: absolute on it? Even positioning your button absolutely, if one of its ancestors has relative or absolute then it will use that as its bounds instead of the body. You could use position fixed to break out of it, but then of course it would always be visible, which may or may not be what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this Liveweave - http://liveweave.com/HCbDKV

So basically I add queries so the container will remove the margin top when the screen size is less than 768px (mobile).

I suggest you to add a class or id for the container because adding a margin value to the container will technically add margin to all containers you are about to make in your project. Let me know.

Comment: Hi. Glad it helps! Accepting the answer would help me too! :)